# openlayers freezing/unresponsive on iPad ios 15 - safari & chrome

Tags: ios, openlayers, openlayers-6

Openlayers freezing +/or unresponsive on ios/iPad.

ios - 15.4.1
iPad - 7th generation
Openlayers v6.14.1 from npm repo.

Problem occurs even if I only have a single OpenStreetMap layer loaded.

Occurs after much zooming in & out &/or rotating.

I've tried disabling rotation, but no difference.

```
const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
      center: fromLonLat ([startLocation.lon, startLocation.lat]),
      zoom: 10,
      constrainResolution: true, // TODO - remove ???
      enableRotation: false
  }),
});

let osm = new TileLayer({
  source: new XYZ({
    url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    attributions: 
      ['&copy; <a target="_blank" href ="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>']
  }),
});

map.addLayer (osm);
```

I've seen that this was an issue back in e.g. 2017: [github issue 2017 #7202](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/7202), and was resolved (?) by editing `ol.interaction.Pointer.prototype.updateTrackedPointers_`

The current `ol`code appears to be:

```
    PointerInteraction.prototype.updateTrackedPointers_ = function (mapBrowserEvent) {
    if (isPointerDraggingEvent(mapBrowserEvent)) {
        var event_1 = mapBrowserEvent.originalEvent;
        var id = event_1.pointerId.toString();
    ...
```

in `ol/interaction/Pointer.js`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the latest development version?  Some outstanding issues have recently been fixed, see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/13771

Comment: That looks like it might do the trick :) Hopefully it will be 'stable' released soon.